# What's the state of the art re really-simple-markup languages and TeX

Tags: markdown

There are a number of simplified text markup languages, including the one use in wikipedia, the one used in stackoverflow, and the one used in github.

I am particulalry interested in githubs language, so called, `[markdown][1]` whose syntax seems as simple as this cheatsheet I just made:

```
# This is like \section
## This is like \subsection
### This is like \subsubsection
#### This is like \paragraph (say)

**bold** text is written like `*bold*` or `__bold__`
**italic** text is written like `*italic*` or `_italic_`

This are list:
- which can be bulleted
- or unbulleted, i.e., numbered
- or checklist.
To be numbered, write numbers, e.g., 1
1. first item
2. second item
1. third item
```

I particularly liked their simplified syntax for simple tables, and if not discouraged by the community, would be asking a related question soon.

Comment: This is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236439/use-markdown-style-formatting-for-bold-and-italic.

Comment: The [last answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240442/114143) in the question @StevenB.Segletes just pointed mentions the [`wiki`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/nicetext/doc/wikicheat.pdf) package, seems to go on the direction you're pointing.

Comment: One can write language-to-TeX converters using either TeX itself (can be tricky) or some scripting approach (often easier). I'm not sure what we can say beyond that!

Comment: It depends on your needs. Do you require multiple output formats? That might favour markdown. Do you need a lot of mathematics? Do  you want to create graphics within your code? Fine control over vertical space, page-breaking? Those things would favour writing LaTeX natively. If you require both fine control and multiple output formats, and you are starting from scratch, without a lot of legacy documents, ConTeXt might be a good way to go.

Comment: For simple documents, `markdown` -> `pandoc` -> `LaTeX`|etc. is great. But as soon as the document gets even a little complicated, you start to miss the macro power of *TeX. For moderately simple things, you can add an intermediate step with [GPP](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html). This [article](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) shows a useful example (for ConTeXt).

Comment: [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) has a LaTeX export, and pandoc can convert from markdown to LaTeX as well.

Comment: Seems as if there are enough comments to make a definite answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConTeXt has a Markdown parser.  From [`m-markdown.mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/beta/tex/context/modules/mkiv/m-markdown.mkiv)

```
This module deals with markdown which is a document encoding that
some \CONTEXT\ like much. It reminds me of the kind of minimal coding
we used before we ran into \TEX\ and were using a somewhat simple
rendering (pagination, etc) of documents. As I'm no user myself, it
is up to others to provide documentation and examples.
```

Things are constantly changing in ConTeXt and according to the above notice, the Markdown module is not a key priority.  Therefore, your example as given above does not typeset as intended.  A more minimal example as the one below however typesets as expected.  If you run into any problem, just ask on the ConTeXt mailing list `ntg-context@ntg.nl`.

Save this as `test.md`.

```
**bold** text is written like `**bold**` or `__bold__`

*italic* text is written like `*italic*` or `_italic_`

This are list:

- which can be bulleted
- or unbulleted, i.e., numbered
- or checklist.

To be numbered, write numbers, e.g., 1

1. first item
2. second item
1. third item
```

Then run it with `context`.

```bash
$ context --extra=markdown test.md
```

The output will be saved to `context-extra.pdf`.

[image]