# Use `code` syntax to insert some code

Tags: listings, code, syntax

Instead of using

```
\usepackage{listings}
...
lstinline{for} or \lstinline{while} or \lstinline{main}
Here you \codeword{see} an \codeword{example} of \codeword{code}
```

**how is it possible to define this syntax for inline-code, similar to Markdown:**

```
Here you `see` an `example` of `code`
```

**?**

Comment: Backticks are generally best avoided, but look at [`fancyvrb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb?lang=en) package or [`shortvrb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/shortvrb) package.  Both can do what you want, perhaps using `|` or `"` as the quote marker.

Comment: Duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361145/15036 ?

Comment: I upvoted this question because it raises an interesting debate about why (not) to use backticks to mark code in LaTeX. Well, maybe it doesn't raise it, but the comments and the answer help in deciding how and when to use them.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with the `fancyvrb` package. I would suggest using a different separator (like `|`) to avoid clashes with quotes etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb{\`}
\begin{document}
Here you `see` an `example` of `code`

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot @TeXnician! Icing on the cake: would it be possible to have `~~~~ This is a piece of code in a block ~~~~` or fenced ```` This too ```` as **block** code (i.e. new paragraph, not inline)?

Comment: @Basj Everything with multiple characters is much more difficult (making one character active is easy). Are you sure you don't want to write markdown source and then use `pandoc` or similar tools to convert that?

Comment: I was initially interested for this solution, but then how do you make chapters, sections, math. etc. inside a document to be converted with Pandoc? I would like to keep `` code `` and ``` code ```, tables, itemization with just `*` from Markdown, but `$math$` and chapters, sections, etc. from LaTeX :) Any idea / example document showing how to use both?

Comment: @Basj Then probably pandoc is the better solution (see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown which shows how to use headers and math) because also markdown tables and itemization is not that easy.

Comment: Small bug: error with this solution `\DefineShortVerb{\`}` when also using `\usepackage{graphicx}`: `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.30     \chardef\mptopdfstoredatcode\catcode`
                                              \@
? 
! Emergency stop.`. If `graphicx` is not loaded, no error...

Comment: @Basj I did mention that it is not a bug, but your choice of characters. Try moving `\DefineShortVerb` as far to the document begin as possible. ` is an essential character for TeX, so you do break things and cause clashes by making it active for some verbatim environment. That is why the LaTeX kernel and others prefer characters like `|`.