# Single-key teletype?

Tags: code, typewriter, markup

I'm writing a document with a ton of pseudocode and it's very tedious to keep wrapping code objects in `{\tt text}`.  It would be so much nicer to, well, do what StackExchange does!  There's a one-character symbol, the back-tick, just like for math there's the dollar-sign.  Is there any way to accomplish the same thing in LaTeX?

Comment: shortverb is your friend

Comment: If you're using VSCode, use `ctrl`+`l`,`ctrl`+`t`.

Comment: _Unrelated:_ don't use two-letter font change commands (`\tt`, `\bf`, etc.) in LaTeX. Use the proper more-letter variants (`\ttfamily`, `\bfseries`, etc.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb|
\begin{document}

this |and| that or |the other|

\end{document}
```

`shortvrb` is in the core `base` latex distribution.

Comment: I suspect this is conflicting with the vertical bars that I'm using to declare borders in tabular environments.  Is that right, and if so, do you happen to know a fix?

Comment: @Addem you can turn it off before the table (`\DeleteShortVerb|` ) or use any other character that you do not use, such as `\MakeShortVerb!` or any other character

Answer (score 11):

Use `fancyvrb` and `\DefineShortVerb` (although you might not want to use `` ` ``)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineShortVerb\`
\begin{document}
I'm writing a document with a ton of pseudocode and it's very tedious to keep wrapping code objects in
`{\tt text}`. It would be so much nicer to, well, do what StackExchange does! There's a one-character
symbol, the back-tick, just like for math there's the dollar-sign. Is there any way to accomplish the same
thing in LaTeX?
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This might cause problems when you want to use quotation marks. A chacter like `|` or `@` might be more suitable

Comment: @AJFarmar That's exactly why I said "you might not want to use `` ` ``", I just used it to imitate the markdown syntax (I could've used more emphasis on that warning, though :-).

Answer (score 4):

What StackExchange does is markdown, so you can also use the [`markdown`](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\begin{markdown}
This `and` that or `the other` 
\end{markdown}
\end{document}
```

Or more simple, write a markdown file and export it to LaTeX:

```
This `and` that or `the other`
```

The bonus point of this approach is avoid also many other tedious commands, not only those for verbatim text.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me adding a link to the package - it was new to me and presumably to others, and looks useful