# Is there a LaTeX-to-HTML package that uses TeX?

Tags: macros, conversion, auxiliary-files, html, latex2html

I know that there are [a lot of ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/convert-latex-to-html) to "convert" LaTeX source to HTML markup that, when rendered, resembles the hypothetical original PDF.

Is there such a package that works within LaTeX? I'm wondering whether to work towards a package (loaded via `\RequirePackage` before the preamble) that applies changes such as `\def\textit#1{<i>#1</i>}`, so that by the final expansion it has written out HTML source to an auxilliary file.

Has this been done? Might it be plausible?

Comment: `tex4ht` uses LaTeX, `htlatex` script in fact is basically `\RequirePackage{tex4ht}\input{filename.tex}`

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38097/15925, also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85438/15925